# Status bar and navigation bar does not seems to have the same color iOS Swift

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar, uistatusbar

I want to set the status bar color the same color as the navigation bar. when I try to set the navigation and status bar to the same color the navigation bar always appear in a lighter color than the status bar.

This is what I want:

[image]

My result:

[image]

Code in AppDelegate:

Status bar:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = .Default
    let statusBar: UIView = UIApplication.sharedApplication().valueForKey("statusBar") as! UIView
    if statusBar.respondsToSelector(Selector("setBackgroundColor:")) 
{
      statusBar.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 43/255.0, green: 79/255.0, blue: 133/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
      statusBar.tintColor = UIColor(red: 43/255.0, green: 79/255.0, blue: 133/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
}
```

Navigation bar:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()]
        UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 43/255.0, green: 79/255.0, blue: 133/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarHidden = false
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = .Default
```

Could anyone give me any suggestion on how to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: set colour of View with the same colour of navigation and this will do what you want

Comment: Is it not as simple as the fact you're using `whiteColor` as the tint on `UINavigationBar` and `UIColor(red: 43/255.0, green: 79/255.0, blue: 133/255.0, alpha: 1.0)` on status bar

Comment: Update yourself to Swift 3, please.

Comment: Yes that is the next step, the current version is in Swift 2.3. After upgrading to Swift 3.0 some feature does not work anymore that's the reason why I left it in Swift 2.3. But we already busy fixing the issues. Since we need to hands it in as soon as possible this was the only solution to leave it in Swift 2.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve the desired result, set the status bar style to default and set the UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor to the required color.

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()]
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(red: 43/255.0, green: 79/255.0, blue: 133/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = .Default
```

Comment: Thanks I got exactly the desired result using your code!

Answer (score 8):

**Warning**! Do not do any of this in iOS 13 or later, and definitely not in iOS 15 or later. This is outdated code from long ago!

---

I was able to get the desired result:

[image]

Here's the code I used (Swift 3):

```
let app = UINavigationBar.appearance()
// nav bar color => your color
app.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 43/255.0, green: 79/255.0, blue: 133/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
app.isTranslucent = false
// status bar text => white
app.barStyle = .black
// nav bar elements color => white
app.tintColor = .white
app.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.white]
```

This line in your code is illegal and will likely get your app banned from the App Store:

```
let statusBar: UIView = UIApplication.sharedApplication().valueForKey("statusBar") as! UIView
```

For the status bar, its color in iOS these days is *clear*. There is no need to set its color, and you are not supposed to do so. The navigation bar is extended up behind the status bar, and thus they will *always* have the same color because what you are seeing is always the same interface object, the navigation bar.

As for setting the navigation bar's color, don't forget that it is translucent by default. You cannot set its color accurately without making it opaque. Also, you should not be setting its `backgroundColor`. You should either set its `barTintColor` or else give it a background image (that is the way to get the best control over its color).

Comment: Browsing through other forums I saw using that piece of code is the only way I can change the status bar color. Since in some section the status must appear in different color.

Answer (score 4):

For me the key was to change the isTranslucent attribute:

```
navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
navigationBar.barTintColor = PlateColors.mainRed
navigationBar.backgroundColor = PlateColors.mainRed
```

Answer (score 1):

based on @matt suggestion to extend navigationbar below status bar, navigation bar must be opaque:

```
    let navigationBar = navigationController?.navigationBar
    navigationBar?.isOpaque = true
    navigationBar?.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(color: UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.5)), for: .default)
    navigationBar?.shadowImage = UIImage()
```

---

```
extension UIImage {

    convenience init?(color: UIColor) {
        let rect = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 1.0, height: 1.0)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size)
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

        context?.setFillColor(color.cgColor)
        context?.fill(rect)

        let image: UIImage? = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        guard let cgImage = image?.cgImage else { return nil }
        self.init(cgImage: cgImage)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who ended up here a little later, like myself (Xcode 13.1, iOS 15.1), this may help:

[In iOS13 the status bar background colour is different from the navigation bar in large text mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56556254/in-ios13-the-status-bar-background-colour-is-different-from-the-navigation-bar-i/57152709#57152709)

It's all about defining the appearances for both `standardAppearance` and `scrollEdgeAppearance` and setting their respective background colors.

Personally, did not even need to solve this programmatically:
[Navigation Bar Attributes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9v6J.png)

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same problem and I have found that it is not the problem of the status bar but the navigation bar. If you set the background color of navigation bar and a simple UIView to the same, the real color shown will be different. To make the color of navigation bar same as another view:

Wrong Code

```
navigationBar.backgroundColor = .blue
view.backgroundColor = .blue
```

Right Code

```
navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
navigationBar.barTintColor = .blue
view.backgroundColor = .blue
```

In this case, their color will be the same.