# Change status bar background color using UIStatusBarManager

Tags: ios, uikit, xcode11, swift5

Earlier on Xcode 10 and swift 5 I used to change the status bar color as follows:-

```
if let statusBar = UIApplication.shared.value(forKey: "statusBar") as? UIView {
   if statusBar.responds(to: #selector(setter: UIView.backgroundColor)) {
      statusBar.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0.7156304717, blue: 0.9302947521, alpha: 1)
   }
}
```

Now on Xcode 11 & Swift 5.1 I get the following error:-

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'App called -statusBar or -statusBarWindow on UIApplication: this code must be changed as there's no longer a status bar or status bar window. Use the statusBarManager object on the window scene instead.'

Any suggestions?

Comment: This question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56651245/how-to-change-the-status-bar-background-color-and-text-color-on-ios-13

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
extension UIApplication {


class var statusBarBackgroundColor: UIColor? {
    get {
        return statusBarUIView?.backgroundColor
    } set {
        statusBarUIView?.backgroundColor = newValue
    }
}

class var statusBarUIView: UIView? {
    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        let tag = 987654321

        if let statusBar = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.viewWithTag(tag) {
            return statusBar
        }
        else {
            let statusBarView = UIView(frame: UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame)
            statusBarView.tag = tag

            UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.addSubview(statusBarView)
            return statusBarView
        }
    } else {
        if responds(to: Selector(("statusBar"))) {
            return value(forKey: "statusBar") as? UIView
        }
    }
    return nil
}}
```

Comment: I keep seeing this answer everywhere. Does it even work? Where does the tag value come from?

Comment: yes it is working like a charm, the value of tag is something that you can decide ... we check that value to not adding the view on subview many times

Comment: I use Xamarin Forms and this works for me, but `keyWindow` wasn't available until `viewWillAppear` is called. So I use it there instead of `FinishedLaunching`

Comment: This is not using the new UIStatusBarManager nor the window.windowScene from iOS 13 (as recommended in the Xcode warning), but the trick does the work !!!,