# How to get the status bar height in iOS 13?

Tags: ios, ios13

In iOS 13 `UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height` warns

> 'statusBarFrame' was deprecated in iOS 13.0: Use the statusBarManager
>   property of the window scene instead.

How do you get the status bar height without using a deprecated API in iOS 13?

Comment: @rmaddy actually, you need it for a lot of things. Also, it is not your task to question functionalities of apps you don't have any background information about.

Comment: My query was meant to get more info so better answers could be provided. Knowing why might give people a chance to offer a better solution. Sometimes people do things incorrectly for the wrong reasons.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

As the warning hints, you can access the `statusBarManager` which has a `statusBarFrame` property. This is defined on your `UIWindow`'s `windowScene`.

```
let height = view.window?.windowScene?.statusBarManager?.statusBarFrame.height ?? 0
```

Comment: If you use it soon after the app launches it returns nil, while the old way would return the proper value. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you all know if the status bar changes height now in IOS 13. I don't think so but I want to make sure.

Comment: @jordan H, This is not working in iOS 13.3 in Xcode 11.3 Can you give update on this.

Comment: use in viewWillLayoutSubviews().

Comment: KeyWindow should be get as: static func getKeyWindow() -> UIWindow?
    {
        return UIApplication
            .shared
            .connectedScenes
            .flatMap { ($0 as? UIWindowScene)?.windows ?? [] }
            .first { $0.isKeyWindow }
    }

Answer (score 34):

Try, I have tried it.

```
let window = UIApplication.shared.windows.filter {$0.isKeyWindow}.first        
let height = window?.windowScene?.statusBarManager?.statusBarFrame.height ?? 0
```

Comment: Why don't you use "UIApplication.shared.keyWindow"?

Comment: keyWindow is now deprecated as well

Answer (score 20):

**Solution:**

This seems to work without any warning in iPhoneX+ devices as well.

Swift 4.2 / 5

```
if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
    let window = UIApplication.shared.windows.first(where: \.isKeyWindow)
    statusBarHeight = window?.windowScene?.statusBarManager?.statusBarFrame.height ?? 0
} else {
    statusBarHeight = UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height
}
```

Try it. Hope it Helps.

Answer (score 18):

**UIApplication.shared.windows** was deprecated in iOS 15.0

**iOS 15**

```
 let statusBarHeight = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes
        .filter {$0.activationState == .foregroundActive }
        .map {$0 as? UIWindowScene }
        .compactMap { $0 }
        .first?.windows
        .filter({ $0.isKeyWindow }).first?
        .windowScene?.statusBarManager?.statusBarFrame.height ?? 0
```

Answer (score 8):

```
var statusBarHeight: CGFloat = 0
if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
    statusBarHeight = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.windowScene?.statusBarManager?.statusBarFrame.height ?? 0
} else {
    statusBarHeight = UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm!! Thanks.. :)

Comment: `keyWindow` is also deprecated in iOS 13

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem as MMV (see their comment on Jordan H's answer), `view.window?.windowScene?.statusBarManager?.statusBarFrame.height` returned nil near the launch of my app. Specifically `view.window` returned nil. I then tried searching through the windows property on UIApplication.shared:

```
for window in UIApplication.shared.windows
```

This returned two windows in my case. Both of the windows had equal, non-nil status bar heights. I'm not sure why there were two windows, but at least both had the same status bar heights. I accessed the status bar heights like so:

```
if let height = window.windowScene?.statusBarManager?.statusBarFrame.height
```

I decided in my case that since there could possibly be different heights to take the largest of the heights for my code. Here is the code I used for my application:

```
let statusBarHeight: CGFloat = {
    var heightToReturn: CGFloat = 0.0
         for window in UIApplication.shared.windows {
             if let height = window.windowScene?.statusBarManager?.statusBarFrame.height, height > heightToReturn {
                 heightToReturn = height
             }
         }
    return heightToReturn
}()
```

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: It did help me a lot! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Learning from the great answers already given here, using `connectScenes` from `UIApplication`, and we can make an extension:

```swift
extension UIApplication {
    var statusBarHeight: CGFloat {
        connectedScenes
            .compactMap {
                $0 as? UIWindowScene
            }
            .compactMap {
                $0.statusBarManager
            }
            .map {
                $0.statusBarFrame
            }
            .map(\.height)
            .max() ?? 0
    }
}
```

Usage:

```swift
let height = UIApplication.shared.statusBarHeight
```

Answer (score 4):

For the latest method of getting statusBarHeight, is as follows:

```
    private lazy var statusBarHeight: CGFloat = {
        var statusBarHeight: CGFloat = 0
        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            let window = UIApplication.shared.windows.filter {$0.isKeyWindow}.first
            statusBarHeight = window?.windowScene?.statusBarManager?.statusBarFrame.height ?? 0
        } else {
            statusBarHeight = UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height
        }
        return statusBarHeight
    }()
```

Answer (score 3):

Worked for me for iOS 15 and higher.

```
extension UIViewController {
    var statusBarHeight: CGFloat {
        guard
            let scene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene,
            let height = scene.statusBarManager?.statusBarFrame.height
        else {
            return 0
        }
        return height
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

### For Objective-C

I'm not sure what is alternative of filter in OC, so I used a for loop to get `keyWindow`. Well, the actual height I get in iPhone 12 is '47' and iPhone 8 with '20'.

```
    CGFloat statusBarHeight;
    if (@available(iOS 13, *)) {
        NSArray *windows = UIApplication.sharedApplication.windows;
        UIWindow *keyWindow = nil;
        
        for (UIWindow *window in windows) {
            if (window.isKeyWindow) {
                keyWindow = window;
                break;
            }
        }
        statusBarHeight = keyWindow.windowScene.statusBarManager.statusBarFrame.size.height;
        NSLog(@"statusBarHeight: %f", statusBarHeight);
    } else {
        statusBarHeight = UIApplication.sharedApplication.statusBarFrame.size.height;
    }
```

Comment: +1 for showing how to get and use keyWindow with windowScene.  My old app has no windowScene.  All I want is the statusBar size.  Also, you posted just four hours before I needed this!

Comment: Glad to help, I'm a Swift dude, recently start to get some Objective-C knowledge. Nowadays, Objective-C stuff is quite rare in the internet, though most of big companies requires Objective-C first.

Answer (score 1):

**for iOS 13:**

in your `SceneDelegate`:

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
 if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
    let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
    let statusBarSize = windowScene.statusBarManager!.statusBarFrame
    ...// initialize your root view controller
 }
}
```

and if you want to pass the value to your `View`s, you can set the value as `Environment` and use it in your `View`s. example:

first we need to create our environment key:

```
struct StatusBarSizeEnvironmentKey: EnvironmentKey {
   public static let defaultValue: CGRect = CGRect()
}

extension EnvironmentValues {
  public var statusBarSize: CGRect {
    set { self[StatusBarSizeEnvironmentKey.self] = newValue }
    get { self[StatusBarSizeEnvironmentKey] }
  }
}
```

and set the value in `SceneDelegate`:

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
 if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
    let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
    let statusBarSize = windowScene.statusBarManager!.statusBarFrame
    window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: YourView()
             .environment(\.statusBarSize, statusBarSize))
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

stolen from accepted answer:

```
guard let sbheight = view.window?.windowScene?.statusBarManager?.statusBarFrame.height else {
     assertionFailure("usage error: VC lifecyclewise it becomes available no earlier than viewDidAppear")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

***For Objective-C***

```
- (CGFloat)statusBarHeight{
    UIWindowScene * scene = nil;
    for (UIWindowScene* wScene in [UIApplication sharedApplication].connectedScenes){
        if (wScene.activationState == UISceneActivationStateForegroundActive){
            scene = wScene;
            break;
        }
    }
    return scene.statusBarManager.statusBarFrame.size.height;
}
```

I think the above is OK too, @ChuckZHB's answer.

Answer (score 0):

This only works if you have a single window app, which is all of the mobile apps and 99% of the iPad apps.

```
let height = UIApplication.shared.windows.first(where: \.isKeyWindow)?.windowScene?.statusBarManager?.statusBarFrame.height ?? 0
```

or if you like to break up the code a bit:

```
let window = UIApplication.shared.windows.first(where: \.isKeyWindow)
let height = window?.windowScene?.statusBarManager?.statusBarFrame.height ?? 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Get statusBarHeight in iOS 15

**In Objective C**

```
UIWindowScene *windowScene = (UIWindowScene *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].connectedScenes.allObjects.firstObject;
UIWindow *keyWindow = nil;
if ([windowScene isKindOfClass:[UIWindowScene class]]) {
    NSArray<UIWindow *> *windows = windowScene.windows;
    for (UIWindow *window in windows) {
        if (window.isKeyWindow) {
            keyWindow = window;
            break;
        }
    }
}

CGRect statusFrame = keyWindow.windowScene.statusBarManager.statusBarFrame;
CGFloat *statusBarHeight = statusFrame.size.height;
```

**In Swift**

```
var keyWindow: UIWindow?
if let windowScene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene,
   let sceneDelegate = windowScene.delegate as? SceneDelegate {
    let windows = windowScene.windows
    keyWindow = windows.first(where: \.isKeyWindow)
}

let statusFrame = keyWindow.windowScene.statusBarManager.statusBarFrame
let statusBarHeight = statusFrame.size.height
```