# Status bar height in SwiftUI in iOS 13

Tags: swiftui, uistatusbar, uiscene

How do you get the current scene's status bar height for use in a SwiftUI view?

It looks like the key is accessing the current scene. From a view controller, [you can use](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57023907/145173) `view.window?.windowScene` to get to the scene, but what about in a SwiftUI view?

Comment: [Get the window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60359808/how-to-access-own-window-within-swiftui-view) and do the same.

Answer (score 1):

Store the window scene in an environment object when creating the view hierarchy. The environment object can be an existing object that you use for other app-wide data.

```swift
final class AppData: ObservableObject {
    let windowScene: UIWindow? // Will be nil in SwiftUI previewers

    init(windowScene: UIWindowScene? = nil) {
        self.windowScene = windowScene
    }
}
```

Set the window scene when you create the environment object. Add the object to the view at the base of your view hierarchy, such as the root view.

```swift
let rootView = RootView().environmentObject(AppData(windowScene: windowScene))
```

Finally, use the window scene to access the status bar height.

```swift
struct MyView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject private var appData: AppData
    ...
    var body: some View {
        SomeView().frame(height: self.appData.windowScene?.statusBarManager?.statusBarFrame.height ?? 0)
    }
}
```