# Change statusbar backgroundColor WITHOUT navigationBar (iOS 13)

Tags: ios, ios13

I'm looking for a way to change the backgroundcolor of the statusBar. There are similar questions, but they all requires a navigationBar. I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57394751/11720147), but it makes no sense. He uses properties who are deprecated.

For iOS 12 and below it was really simple to change the backgroundcolor:

```
let statusBar: UIView = UIApplication.shared.value(forKey: "statusBar") as! UIView
statusBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
```

But for iOS 13 it looks really complicated. Is there no similar way to change it?

Comment: FYI - that iOS 12 code has never been valid or supported since it required digging into a private API. All such solutions, even if they work at one point, are prone to failure with any iOS update.

Comment: So, there is **no** official way to change the statusbar backgroundColor?

Answer (score 0):

You can use following way to change the status bar color. It will work for iOS 13. I hope it will work for you

```
guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
if let statusBarFrame = windowScene.statusBarManager?.statusBarFrame {
     let statusBarHeight = statusBarFrame.size.height
     let statusBarView = UIView.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: -statusBarHeight, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: statusBarHeight))
     statusBarView.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
     self.navigationController?.navigationBar.addSubview(statusBarView)
}
```

Here is reference link
[How to change the status bar background color and text color on iOS 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19063365/how-to-change-the-status-bar-background-color-and-text-color-on-ios-7)