# Change Status Bar Color in iOS 13?

Tags: ios, swift

I have been trying to change Status Bar Color but using key statusBar my app is crashing.
I guess key "statusBar" is not available in iOS 13.

```
let statusBar: UIView = UIApplication.shared.value(forKey: "statusBar") as! UIView
if statusBar.responds(to: #selector(setter: UIView.backgroundColor)) {
  statusBar.backgroundColor = <Some Color>
}
```

adding view also not working for me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the status bar background color and text color on iOS 13?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56651245/how-to-change-the-status-bar-background-color-and-text-color-on-ios-13)

Comment: Share console log please with crash reason.

Comment: @DharmeshKheni got this crash:                                                                                                     *** Assertion failure in -[UIApplication _createStatusBarWithRequestedStyle:orientation:hidden:], *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'App called -statusBar or -statusBarWindow on UIApplication: this code must be changed as there's no longer a status bar or status bar window. Use the statusBarManager object on the window scene instead.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1st way**

You can check iOS version and add custom status bar like this ->

```swift
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    if #available(iOS 13, *) {
        let statusBar = UIView(frame: (UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.windowScene?.statusBarManager?.statusBarFrame)!)
        statusBar.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.addSubview(statusBar)
    }
}
```

**2nd way**

You can customize `UINavigationBarAppearance`

```swift
if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
    let navBarAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
    navBarAppearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
    navBarAppearance.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
    navBarAppearance.largeTitleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
    navBarAppearance.backgroundColor = <yourColor>
    navigationBar.standardAppearance = navBarAppearance
    navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = navBarAppearance
}
```