# How to find status bar subviews in iOS 13?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Tried some methods but showing deprecated in iOS 13.

```
let application = UIApplication.shared
let statusBarView = application.value(forKey: "statusBar") as! UIView
```

```
"App called -statusBar or -statusBarWindow on UIApplication: this code must be changed as there's no longer a status bar or status bar window. Use the statusBarManager object on the window scene instead.'"
```

Comment: Try searching for "Use the statusBarManager object on the window scene instead."

Comment: @koen Using status bar manager dont give statusBarViews

Comment: First hit: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56651245/how-to-change-the-status-bar-background-color-and-text-color-on-ios-13