# iOS 13 window background color

Tags: ios, background-color, uiwindow, ios13

[image]

The image above is in dark mode, with the following setup in the app delegate:

```
if (@available(iOS 13.0, *)) {
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor systemBackgroundColor];
}
```

The problem is that the top white should be black in dark mode.
How can I make that happen?

Thanks.

Comment: In iOS 13 the window belongs to the scene delegate, not the app delegate.

Comment: @matt interesting.. I do have a valid window object though in the app delegate: `<UIWindow: 0x7fe94dd08160; frame = (0 0; 375 812); hidden = YES; tintColor = UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 0.01 0.5 0.401961 1; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x60000273a2e0>; layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x60000297ba40>>`
I wonder why it says `hidden`..
The view hierarchy debugger prints: `<UIWindow: 0x7fe94dd08160; frame = (0 0; 375 812); autoresize = W+H; tintColor = UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 0.0627451 0.501961 0.501961 1; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x60000273a2e0>; layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x60000297ba40>>`

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/a/57152709/8687925

Comment: @matt I got your point now.. slowly sinking in.. thanks

Comment: @Zsolt Did you finally find the solution? I am getting the same problem here.

Answer (score 1):

Is it still the issue? Here is my code which redirect to `initialViewController` based on login status. And it is working.

```
if let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate {
    appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
    appDelegate.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
         appDelegate.window?.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
    }else{
         appDelegate.window?.backgroundColor = .white // as you want
    }
 }
```