# Change status bar background color in iOS13

Tags: ios, statusbar, ios13

With iOS13 I cannot change the background color of the statusbar anymore because the statusbar is no longer accessible using "value for key".
Did anybody figure out how this is possible or is there any knowledge that it will be possible in the final version of iOS13?

I came across different proposals already like using the UIApplications StatusBarView (no longer accessible in xcode 11, beta 7) or using the statusbarmanager. Both do not give access to the status bar.

```swift
let statusBar: UIView = UIApplication.shared.value(forKey: "statusBar") as! UIView
if statusBar.responds(to: #selector(setter: UIView.backgroundColor)) {
  statusBar.backgroundColor = <Some Color>
}
```

I expect the status bar to get the background color that I need.

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/57152709/8687925.

Comment: Thanks @SAXENA - this seems to require a navigationbar to set the appearance on. I am looking for a way without navigationbar.

Comment: @Nij see this for help : [How to change the status bar background color and text color on iOS 13?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56651245/how-to-change-the-status-bar-background-color-and-text-color-on-ios-13)

Answer (score 9):

Objective-C Version using UIStatusBarManager:

```
UIView *statusBar = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.windowScene.statusBarManager.statusBarFrame] ;
statusBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow addSubview:statusBar]
```

Comment: Note: For those not using SceneDelegate just use `[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame`

Answer (score 7):

Use this on your preferred ViewController

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    if #available(iOS 13, *)
    {
        let statusBar = UIView(frame: (UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.windowScene?.statusBarManager?.statusBarFrame)!)
        statusBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemBackground
        UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.addSubview(statusBar)
    }
}
```

you can use your Color in "UIColor.systemBackground"

Comment: Do we need to add this to every ViewController? What if we want to perform in the entire app.

Comment: Not working coz 'keyWindow' was deprecated in iOS 13.0: Should not be used for applications that support multiple scenes as it returns a key window across all connected scenes

Comment: How to remove the statusBar when viewWillDisappear() is called?

Comment: @ShubhamGupta did you find a solution to perform in the entire app??

Answer (score 7):

**Code works for Swift 5+ and iOS 13+**

To change the StatusBar background colour, i have created a base class of UIViewController so that i can inherit same code in all the view controllers.

Added "statusBarColorChange()" to UIViewController extension.

```
extension UIViewController {

  func statusBarColorChange() {

    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {

        let statusBar = UIView(frame: UIApplication.shared.windows.filter {$0.isKeyWindow}.first?.windowScene?.statusBarManager?.statusBarFrame ?? CGRect.zero)
        statusBar.backgroundColor = .appNavigationThemeColor
            statusBar.tag = 100
        UIApplication.shared.windows.filter {$0.isKeyWindow}.first?.addSubview(statusBar)

    } else {

            let statusBar = UIApplication.shared.value(forKeyPath: "statusBarWindow.statusBar") as? UIView
            statusBar?.backgroundColor = .appNavigationThemeColor

        }
    } }
```

Created Base Class and inherited in other classes.

```
class BaseClass: UIViewController {

   override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
       self.statusBarColorChange()
   }    
}

class ChatListViewController: BaseClass {}
```

Hope will be helping :)

Answer (score 2):

You can just set the base view background color in your ViewController if you are not using NavigationController

```
view.backgroundColor = .blue
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
    let navBarAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
    navBarAppearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
    navBarAppearance.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
    navBarAppearance.largeTitleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
    navBarAppearance.backgroundColor = <insert your color here>
    navigationBar.standardAppearance = navBarAppearance
    navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = navBarAppearance
}
```

Comment: no it didn't help that fixed NavigationBar color only not status bar color

Answer (score 1):

### The status bar will try and match the color of the app

if you have a navbar

```
self.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.blue

or

UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.blue
```

if there is no navbar

```
view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
```

if your background is a webview

```
webView.scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
```

*there are probably more cases I'm missing*

Answer (score 1):

There is one issue observed by following **@JaspreetKour's** answer, in which the status bar view is getting added again and again which makes the status bar colour darker than the applied colour, This happens if we are navigating to the same view controller multiple time by means of push/pop VC.

So I added two line of code to resolve that issue, in case any one facing same issue can check out this answer, where I removed the status bar view first before adding it again on window.

And then call it on `viewDidLoad` instead of `viewWillAppear`

```
func statusBarColorChange() {
    
    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        if let viewStatus =  UIApplication.shared.windows.filter {$0.isKeyWindow}.first{
            viewStatus.viewWithTag(100)?.removeFromSuperview()
        }
        
        let statusBar = UIView(frame: UIApplication.shared.windows.filter {$0.isKeyWindow}.first?.windowScene?.statusBarManager?.statusBarFrame ?? CGRect.zero)
        statusBar.backgroundColor = AppConstant.Colors.navColor
        statusBar.tag = 100
        UIApplication.shared.windows.filter {$0.isKeyWindow}.first?.addSubview(statusBar)
        
    } else {
        let statusBar = UIApplication.shared.value(forKeyPath: "statusBarWindow.statusBar") as? UIView
        statusBar?.backgroundColor = AppConstant.Colors.navColor
    }
}
```

---

```
class BaseClass: UIViewController {

   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       self.statusBarColorChange()
   }    
}

class ChatListViewController: BaseClass {}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
 appearance.backgroundColor = .blue
 self.navigationController?.navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
```

I hope, this will help you.

Comment: no it didn't help that fixed NavigationBar color only not status bar color

Answer (score 0):

**Call this in your base view controller**

```
public extension UIViewController {
    func setStatusBar(color: UIColor) {
        let tag = 12321
        if let taggedView = self.view.viewWithTag(tag){
            taggedView.removeFromSuperview()
        }
        let overView = UIView()
        overView.frame = UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame
        overView.backgroundColor = color
        overView.tag = tag
        self.view.addSubview(overView)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JaspreetKour's answer works; but, it can be very difficult to reset the status bar color for other view controllers (especially if you need image content underneath the status bar). Setting the color to .clear does not work.

A simpler solution is to clear the navigation bar:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = .clear
navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
```

and then add a UIView (set the background color to the color you need) to your view controller and set its constraints to the very top of your superview (not to the margin).

With this technique, your color will show underneath the status bar and you won't need to mess with the statusBarManager (whose properties are all read only).

Answer (score 0):

**Code works for Swift 5+ and iOS 13+**

```
    public extension UIViewController {

func setStatusBar(color: UIColor) {
    
    let keyWindow = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes
        .filter({$0.activationState == .foregroundActive})
        .compactMap({$0 as? UIWindowScene})
        .first?.windows
        .filter({$0.isKeyWindow}).first
    
    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        
        let statusBar = UIView(frame: keyWindow?.windowScene?.statusBarManager?.statusBarFrame ?? CGRect.zero)
        statusBar.backgroundColor = color
        statusBar.tag = 100
        keyWindow?.addSubview(statusBar)
        
    } else {
        
        let statusBar = UIApplication.shared.value(forKeyPath: "statusBarWindow.statusBar") as? UIView
        statusBar?.backgroundColor = color
        
    }}}
```

I use this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64924164/6694595) but in this case compiler generates warning

> 'windows' was deprecated in iOS 15.0: Use UIWindowScene.windows on a relevant window scene instead

so this code work fine.

and in your **ViewController** viewDidLoad Method use this method as follows:

```
setStatusBar(color: UIColor(red: 28/255, green: 83/255, blue: 167/255, alpha: 1)) // or whatever color you want to set
```

Answer (score -1):

I was using central ThemeManager class where I was setting all UI colors. This is how I solved it. You can take parts of solution which fit your need:

```
  let sharedApplication = UIApplication.shared
  sharedApplication.delegate?.window??.tintColor = setYourColor

  if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        let statusBar = UIView(frame: (sharedApplication.delegate?.window??.windowScene?.statusBarManager?.statusBarFrame)!)
        statusBar.backgroundColor = setYourColor
        sharedApplication.delegate?.window??.addSubview(statusBar)
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
        sharedApplication.statusBarView?.backgroundColor = setYourColor
  }



extension UIApplication {

var statusBarView: UIView? {
    return value(forKey: "statusBar") as? UIView
   }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
if let statusBar = UIStatusBarManager.self as? UIView {
    if statusBar.responds(to: #selector(setter: UIView.backgroundColor)) {
        statusBar.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
    }
}
```

I hope this works for you

Comment: I need in obj c not swift

Comment: As far as I know there currently is no way to do this in Objective-C @Vinodh

Comment: Cast from 'UIStatusBarManager.Type' to unrelated type 'UIView' always fails