# How can I change the statusBarFrame color to keep the same as the NavigationController in Swift iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift, ios13

I open a `modal` with below code.
I am using `.fullScreen` because I need `viewWillAppear` called after this `controller` is dismissed.

```
let controller = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Login")
controller.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

When the controller is presented:

[image: top]

My problem is, **how can I change the top color to keep the same as the navigation?**

Comment: Which iOS version are you developing to?

Comment: I am with iOS 13

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56556254/in-ios13-the-status-bar-background-colour-is-different-from-the-navigation-bar-i.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For iOS 13 you can use [`UINavigationBarAppearance`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationbarappearance), as seen on the docs and on this [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56556254/in-ios13-the-status-bar-background-colour-is-different-from-the-navigation-bar-i).

```
if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
    let navBarAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
    navBarAppearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
    navBarAppearance.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
    navBarAppearance.largeTitleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
    navBarAppearance.backgroundColor = <insert your color here>
    navigationBar.standardAppearance = navBarAppearance
    navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = navBarAppearance
}
```