# iOS 14 large titles not working properly when navigating between views

Tags: ios, swift, ios14

Large titles disappear after navigating back and forth within the app. The large title is enabled but when navigating back, it becomes small again. This only happened when updating to iOS 14.

Comment: Try to configure your nav bar with large title with my extension https://stackoverflow.com/a/58361310/5575955 or put the screen of your views to explain...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64005273/ios14-navigationitem-largetitledisplaymode-always-not-work